# How can I extract total time used by an employee from a record mainted in a different tab

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I add the time used by an employee for different taks and keep track for the total time used in a particular week? Staff will flight out a few times per week with each flight date and time recorded in one tab per week.  I would like to maintain of a weekly record for each employee total time.
Tab called WK1
A2 - name
M2 - total flight time
in a tab called Monthly Tabulation I would like to have the list of each employee and be able to extract the time from column M (WK1) each time the employee's name is typed in column A from WK1.

Answer (score 0):

If the information is in the correct format then you can use a pivot table.

http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html